# Query with relationship fields

Tags: apex, lookup, query, relationships

I read some other questions but I'm still having trouble.

I' ve got Custom object `A` and `B`. `A` has got a LookUp relationship field on `B` named `LookUpB__c`.

I'd like to get the value of Name of B. This is the query I'm using:

```
SELECT Name FROM B WHERE id =: A.LookUpB__c
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So are you looking for a particular record or just all the names of B? The way your query is set up right now (when fixed) will just grab all the names of B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

// Assuming you are querying object A , need to use (__r) to retrieve Parent fields.

__r is for Custom objects reference For example: Custom_Object__r . It is used for reference custom object relationship name in Apex or visualforce page, formula field etc. Used as suffix.

```
String strBName = [SELECT Id, LookUpB__c, LookUpB__r.Name FROM A WHERE Id=: 'Id of Record A' limit 1].LookUpB__r.Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to just grab the Name of Object B when given Object A you should try this:

```
SELECT Id, LookUpB__c.Name FROM A WHERE Id= [Id of Object A]
```